# How do you backup and restore a database as a copy on the same server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, restore

I have a SQL2005 Express database that I would like to create a copy of on the same instance.  How do you go about doing this with a script?

I already have a script for generating the backup, but the restore is failing...

**THE ERROR:**

> Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Logical file 'MyDB_data' is not part
>   of database 'MyDB_Test'. Use RESTORE
>   FILELISTONLY to list the logical file
>   names.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 2 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally.

**THE RESOLUTION:**

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB_Test]
FROM DISK = 'C:\temp\SQL\MyDB.bak'
WITH
MOVE 'MyDB' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_Test.mdf'
, MOVE 'MyDB_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_Test_log.ldf'
, REPLACE;
```

**THE REASON:**
I did not identify the logical path correctly in my first attempt.

Comment: This is not a Server Fault question.  I'm writing an application that will do this work...

Comment: Just updated my answer after seeing the edits you made.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`RESTORE FILELISTONLY`  is an informational command and is not required to perform a restore.  A user can use this to figure out what the logical names are for the data files, that can be used with the `MOVE` commands to restore the database to a new location.

As suggested by the error message you need to use `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` to see what the logical names for the database are.  Your restore command has these wrong.

Here is a working example of what you need to do:

```
--backup the database
backup database test1 to disk='c:\test1_full.bak'

-- use the filelistonly command to work out  what the logical names 
-- are to use in the MOVE commands.  the logical name needs to
-- stay the same, the physical name can change
restore filelistonly from disk='c:\test1_full.bak'
 --------------------------------------------------
|  LogicalName  |           PhysicalName           |
 --------------------------------------------------
| test1         | C:\mssql\data\test1.mdf          |
| test1_log     | C:\mssql\data\test1_log.ldf      |
 -------------------------------------------------

restore database test2 from disk='c:\test1_full.bak'
with move 'test1' to 'C:\mssql\data\test2.mdf',
move 'test1_log' to 'C:\mssql\data\test2.ldf'
```

Answer (score 6):

[How to: Restore a Database to a New Location and Name (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190447.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives:

Database restore (from .BAK) softwares::

1) [SqlRestoreSetup](https://www.google.ge/search?q=One-Click%20SQL%20Restore)

2)  [Apex SQL Restore](https://www.google.ge/search?q=Apex%20SQL%20Restore)