# How to insert results of select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am a C# dev learning SQL.

I need to publish data from one database, to another which already has the same structure and which are both on the same instance of Sql Server.  By publish, I mean I want all the id's and data to be exactly the same.

The second database is an exact copy of the first.

This is the query:

```
Select vev.* from [dbo].[metadata_document_set] mds

inner join
[dbo].[document_metadata] dm
on mds.metadata_document_set_id = dm.metadata_document_set_id

inner join [dbo].[segment_metadata] sm
on dm.document_metadata_id = sm.document_metadata_id

inner join [dbo].[element_metadata] em
on sm.segment_metadata_id = em.segment_metadata_id

inner join [dbo].[valid_element_value] vev
on em.element_metadata_id = vev.element_metadata_id

where mds.code = 'PA'
```

I need to insert all the rows of valid_element_values, as well as element_metadata, segment_metadata, and document_metadata.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have table already created in target database ?

Comment: Yes, the tables and structure is already created.

Comment: Then you can simply run a `INSERT` statement. Remove `vev.*` and mention the columns from all four table in same order as your Insert column list

Comment: @Prdp, I don't understand what you mean by 'mention the columns from all four tables.'  An example would be great.

Comment: do you want to insert these rows into one table? or into separate tables?

Comment: This may have been answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043726/best-way-to-copy-a-database-sql-server-2008

Comment: @Stephen, Separate tables.

Comment: then you will have to insert one table at a time, cannot do it in one join

Comment: If any table use`IDENTITY` columns be careful, they would need special treatment

Answer (score 2):

If you are inserting to separate tables, you will have to do it one insert at a time.

```
insert [new_database_name].[dbo].[metadata_document_set]
Select * from [old_database_name].[dbo].[metadata_document_set] 
where code = 'PA'

insert [new_database_name].[dbo].[document_metadata]
Select * from [old_database_name].[dbo].[document_metadata] 
<filter as required>
```

and so on.

This assumes your tables are exactly the same.

**NB** This will not work if you have `INDENTITY` columns.

Comment: @Horaciux *disclamer* added

Answer (score 1):

`Select vev.*` will select columns only from `valid_element_value` table so remove `vev.*` from `select` and mention the `columns` from all four table in same order as your `Insert` column list

Considering the target tables are created with all the required column in target database

**Update :** Looks like you want to insert into four different tables. Then you need four different `Insert` statements

```
INSERT INTO target_database.SCHEMA.target_valid_element_value
            (vev_col1,
             vev_col2,
             ..)
SELECT vev.col1,
       vev.col2,
       ..
FROM   [dbo].[metadata_document_set] mds
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[document_metadata] dm
               ON mds.metadata_document_set_id = dm.metadata_document_set_id
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[segment_metadata] sm
               ON dm.document_metadata_id = sm.document_metadata_id
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[element_metadata] em
               ON sm.segment_metadata_id = em.segment_metadata_id
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[valid_element_value] vev
               ON em.element_metadata_id = vev.element_metadata_id
WHERE  mds.code = 'PA' 


INSERT INTO target_database.SCHEMA.target_element_metadata
            (em_col1,
             em_col2,
             ..)
SELECT em.col1,
       em.col2,
       ..
FROM   [dbo].[metadata_document_set] mds
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[document_metadata] dm
               ON mds.metadata_document_set_id = dm.metadata_document_set_id
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[segment_metadata] sm
               ON dm.document_metadata_id = sm.document_metadata_id
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[element_metadata] em
               ON sm.segment_metadata_id = em.segment_metadata_id
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[valid_element_value] vev
               ON em.element_metadata_id = vev.element_metadata_id
WHERE  mds.code = 'PA'
```

Regarding Identity, If you have `identity` column in your target tables and you want insert values from source for those columns as well then

```
set Identity_insert target_table ON 
<<Insert statement>>
set Identity_insert target_table OFF
```

If you dont want to explicitly insert values into identity column then dont add identity column in `Insert` & `Select` column list

Comment: You are not considering the use of `Identity` columns

Comment: @Horaciux - Updated my post for `Identity` property

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have [dbo1].[metadata_document_set1] table (and it has all the columns in select query)then

```
INSERT INTO [dbo1].[metadata_document_set1]
Select vev.*,em.*,sm.*,dm.*,mds.* from [dbo].[metadata_document_set] mds        
inner join [dbo].[document_metadata] dm

on mds.metadata_document_set_id = dm.metadata_document_set_id

inner join [dbo].[segment_metadata] sm
on dm.document_metadata_id = sm.document_metadata_id

inner join [dbo].[element_metadata] em
on sm.segment_metadata_id = em.segment_metadata_id

inner join [dbo].[valid_element_value] vev
on em.element_metadata_id = vev.element_metadata_id

where mds.code = 'PA'
```