# How to create copy of database using backup and restore

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, copy, ms-query

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2012, I'm trying to create a copy of a local database. I found a few variants of solution. One of them - backup and restore database as new one - [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190447%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

Currently create database backup with name `Rewards2_bak`. This copy of file place in to system catalog `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\`

[image]

Next step - create query for restoring database as copy of existing one

```
GO
use master
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
    FROM Rewards2_bak

RESTORE DATABASE Rewards2_Copy
    FROM Rewards2_bak
    WITH RECOVERY,
    MOVE 'Rewards2_data' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Rewards2_copy.mdf',
    MOVE 'Rewards2_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Rewards2_log_copy.ldf'
GO
```

Got error, that I don't have a backup device `Rewads2_backup`. I'm right understand that in this case like device i can use file, and also file location? Think something missing...

For creating backup use next query (all OK)

```
USE Rewards2;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE Rewards2
TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Rewards2_bak.bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of Rewards2';
GO
```

Also try to use tools in SQL Server 2012 `Task --> Backup` and `Task --> Restore`, but got error - can't create backup. (Launched program with Administrator rights)

This is screen how I config restore to copy

[image]

But I have error, that I can't overwrite database file `Rewards2`. And this is question - why it wants to overwrite `Rewards2` if I put new name of database `Rewards2_copy`. Or I understand something wrong?

[image]

Shure, that ther is a few more possible variants for making copy of database, but really whant to find problem for this solution. Where i make mistake/ what I forget or don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you restore a database from a backup it will use the same file names as the original database.
You need to change these file names during the restore.

On the restore window go to the `Files` tab. On this window you have a column called `Restore As`.
Change the file names at the end of the path in the column Restore As  for each of the files you see.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to overwrite the logical filenames from the database you are trying to copy...guessing a bit but try this - try it in SSMS if you don't need to script it right now:

1. Backup the database you want to copy (Rewards2_bak.bak is fine)
2. Create a new database (Rewards2_copy)
3. Restore into Rewards2_copy using Rewards2_bak.bak

Remember in point three to change the logical  filenames within the options tab - otherwise you will try and overwrite the Rewards2 files.

There are lots of guides around:

- [Copy Database with Backup and Restore](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190436.aspx)
- [Copy Database to other servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189624.aspx)
- [How do you backup and restore a database as a copy on the same server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360529/how-do-you-backup-and-restore-a-database-as-a-copy-on-the-same-server)

Via SQL to determine the logical filenames you can use: filelistonly

```
restore filelistonly from disk='enter backup file path here'
```

Then use the filenames reported to build you restore query, as you have already tried

Comment: Do step by step, also after all of this attach new database with different name. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer from @JodyT:

In my case you not only needed to change the logical file names, but it is also important to remove the option "Take tail-log backup before restore".
If this option is checked, then you cannot restore to Rewards2_copy if Rewards2 is in use!

Answer (score 0):

Here is VBS script that will backup and restore DB to another server.  It assumes that each server has "Backup" file share.  The script can be run from any location.

```
sFrom  = "\\server1\Backup"
sTo = "\\server2\Backup"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

CopyDb "Db1"
CopyDb "Db2"

MsgBox "Done!"

Sub CopyDb(sDB)

  If fso.FileExists(sFrom & "\" & sDB & ".bak") Then
     fso.DeleteFile sFrom & "\" & sDB & ".bak"
  End If

  ExecuteSql "server1", "BACKUP DATABASE " & sDB & " TO DISK = '" & sFrom & "\" & sDB & ".bak'"

  fso.CopyFile sFrom & "\" & sDB & ".bak",  sTo & "\" & sDB & ".bak"

  ExecuteSql "server2", "ALTER DATABASE " & sDB & " SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"
  ExecuteSql "server2", "RESTORE DATABASE " & sDB & " FROM  DISK = N'" & sTo & "\" & sDB & ".bak'"
  ExecuteSql "server2", "EXEC " & sDB & ".dbo.sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'user1', 'user1'"
End Sub

Sub ExecuteSql(sServer, sSql)
  Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=" & sServer
  cn.Execute sSql
  cn.Close
End Sub
```